# Do I need the "3f" at the end of these OpenGL functions?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

OK so I am trying to write some code in C++ and try experimenting around and tinkering with OpenGL like some crazed toddler. But the problem is I keep on stumbling across `3f` every time time you try to call a vertex or set a color you have to write `glColor3f` or `glVertex3f`

For example in this triangle,

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
       glColor3f(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)
            glVertex3f(x,y,z)
            glVertex3f(x,y,z)
            glVertex3f(x,y,z)
```

Now I could have just not gone to the effort and wrote:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
       glColor(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)
            glVertex(x,y,z)
            glVertex(x,y,z)
            glVertex(x,y,z)
```

You see without a `3f` that nobody has made clear to me why is there.

Please somebody tell me what this `3f` means. I thought it was like some hexadecimal or something which makes 63 which still doesn't make any sense

Comment: "*i could have just not gone to the effort and wrote*" Not in C++, you couldn't. Then again, in C++, each of those lines would need a `;` at the end of them. So there's a lot about this "code" that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

Because OpenGL is a C API and in C there is no function overloading, but OpenGL wants to provide the ability to supply your data directly in a specific format, there are differently named versions for these functions with different argument types.

e.g. [glVertex](http://docs.gl/gl2/glVertex)

If you can really compile a bare `glVertex`, it is a shortcut for one of the other versions, but i don’t believe that that’s per spec, so you probably shouldn’t use it.

Comment: ahh so your saying that because there is no function overloading they just added 3f so it wouldnt cause a conflict like my user name is kitten67 but it would have been just kitten but already taken so reluctantly i had to add a 67

Comment: @armanddebruijn: Function suffixes [are not arbitrary](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Nomenclature#Function_suffixes). Also, are you asking what those suffixes mean, or are you asking why your code works without them? Because the way your question is written, it clearly seems to be the latter.

Comment: @NicolBolas ahh so function suffix is what you call them ok i see i guess yes i am wondering why it works without them but also why specifically a "3" and an "f" 3f

Comment: @armanddebruijn i would say it doesn’t work without it (i have never seen it). On which OS are you using freeglut on? `3f` is explained in Nicol’s link. `3` is the number of arguments and `f` stands for `GLfloat` which is probably always `float`.

Comment: @Darklighter ahh insightful answer i now see what 3f means thank you

Comment: @Darklighter oh yea im running debian 10 and i didnt know that they didnt work work without them i thought the other guy said function suffixes are not arbitrary

Comment: @Darklighter could you elaborate on nicols link this sounds like something i should have known from the get go ive googled it but i guess its too specific

Comment: The problem the '3f' solves is that in 'C' dll's (e.g. your openGL driver) there is no name mangling. This means that different overloads for a function (e.g. glVertex with combinations of 2D/3D/4D, or float/int/double) will all be named in the export table of the DLL as 'glVertex'. This means you wouldn't know which method is correct for your data type. C++ fixed this problem with name mangling (i.e. encode the parameters as part of the symbol name). OpenGL manually encodes the arguments in the function name to skirt around this issue. OpenGL targets C, so sticks to the rules of C. That's all

Comment: @armanddebruijn what do you want elaborated? you can click the `are not arbitrary` in his comment the same way you can click the `glVertex` in my answer. The links provide quite some elaboration already, so i’m not sure what’s unclear.

Comment: @Darklighter oml man im so sorry i just realised by nicols link you meant the link from nicol sorry man im kinda trippin hard rn tryna execute ma c++ i thought you were talking about some magic manual from the creators called nicols link im so sorry for wasting ur time like that

Comment: @armanddebruijn: Just FYI: When C++ code is compiled, the compiler will mangle the function names based on their parameters, so to avoid name conflicts and so that when the program is linked the right overloaded functions are used, depending on the types of the passed parameters. In C++ it happens behind the scenes, in C it is done explicitly by the programmer.